# Unsubscribe from watchPositionAsync with useEffect return function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks

Using react native with expo-location for a mobile app, I would like to unsubscribe from `Location.watchPositionAsync` which returns a promise with a `remove()` method to unsubscribe.
I call the function within a useEffect hooks, but i don't know how to correctly return a cleanup function with the watchPositionAsync promise resolved.

Any suggestions?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

import * as Location from "expo-location";

export const GpsComponent = function () {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const positionSubscription = async () => {
            const positionSubscribe = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
                { accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.BestForNavigation },
                (newLocation) => {
                    setLocation(newLocation);
                }
            );

            return positionSubscribe;
        };

        /*return () => {
            positionSubscription.remove();
            console.log("Unsubscribed from WatchPositionAsync");
        };*/

    }, [setLocation]);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(location)}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This will create the watchPositionAsync subscription and pass the correct remove function as the cleanup of the useEffect. A dummy subscription is created initially with a nop remove function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // nop subscription. in case not successful
    let subscription = { remove: () => {} }

    // subscribe async function
    const subscribe = async () => {
      return await Location.watchPositionAsync(
        { accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.Highest },
        (newLocation) => {
          setLocation(newLocation)
        }
      )
    }

    // return subscription promise
    subscribe()
      .then(result => subscription = result)
      .catch(err => console.warn(err))

    // return remove function for cleanup
    return subscription.remove
  }, [])
```

Comment: Sorry not really making sense, as this useEffect subscribe and then unsubscribe at same time because the empty array and is run only after first render

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to unsubscribe to `watchPositionAsync` using `useRef`

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

import * as Location from "expo-location";

export const GpsComponent = function () {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const unsubscribe = useRef(() => undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscribe= async () => {
            
            const positionSubscription = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
                { accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.BestForNavigation },
                (newLocation) => {
                    setLocation(newLocation);
                }
            );

           unsubscribe.current=()=>{positionSubscription?.remove()}
        };

     return ()=>{unsubscribe.current()}
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(location)}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

It 's also possible to use an object and modify a property after the async function's promise is resolved.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the 'subscribe' function you create in useEffect is never called in the example above. Does this actually work?